# Fragment Shader Multiple Output and Reading from FrameBuffer Object Issue

Tags: c++, opengl, fragment-shader, framebuffer, glreadpixels

I have 2 outputs in fragment shader first one's output color (RGBA)  and the second one's is a number which will serve as an id but I try to read it from frameBuffer it always returns 0.
The way how I read from FBO:

```
int FrameBuffer::ReadPixels(float x,float y, int attachment)
{
    GLerror(glReadBuffer(GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0+attachment));
    int value;
    GLerror(glReadPixels(x,y, 1, 1, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_INT, &value));
    return value;
}
```

And this method called in loop like:

```
        FBO.Bind();
    renderer.Clear();
    renderer.Draw(Circle_VAO, Circle_Shader, Circle_IB);
    renderer.Draw(Quad_VAO, Quad_Shader, Quad_IB);
    std::cout << FBO.ReadPixels(450,360,1) << std::endl;
    FBO.Unbind();
```

These are the FBO attachments:

```
GLerror(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, m_RendererID));

    
    GLerror(glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &m_RendererColorAttachments[0]));
    GLerror(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererColorAttachments[0]));
    GLerror(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA8, 1820.0, 720.0, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLerror(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0 , GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererColorAttachments[0], 0));
    GLerror(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));

    GLerror(glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &m_RendererColorAttachments[1]));
    GLerror(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererColorAttachments[1]));
    GLerror(glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_R32I, 1820.0, 720.0, 0, GL_RED_INTEGER, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLerror(glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP_TO_EDGE));
    GLerror(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererColorAttachments[1], 0));
    GLerror(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
    
    GLerror(glCreateTextures(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, &m_RendererDepthID));
    GLerror(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererDepthID));
    GLerror(glTexStorage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 1, GL_DEPTH24_STENCIL8, 1820.0, 720.0));
    GLerror(glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_STENCIL_ATTACHMENT, GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_RendererDepthID, 0));
    GLerror(glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0));
    auto fboS = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
    if (fboS != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
        std::cout << "FRAMEBUFFER INCOMPLETE  " << fboS << std::endl;
    GLerror(glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0));
```

Fragment and vertex Shader:

```
    #shader vertex
    #version 460 core
        layout(location=0) in vec3 position;
        layout(location=1) in vec3 colors;
        layout(location=2) in vec2 texCoords;
        layout(location=3) in int a_ObjectID;
        uniform mat4 u_MVP;
        out vec3 v_Colors;
        out flat int v_ObjectID;
        void main()
        {
            gl_Position=u_MVP*vec4(position,1.0);
            v_ObjectID = a_ObjectID;
            v_Colors=colors;
        };

    #shader fragment
    #version 460 core

        layout(location=0) out vec4 color;
        layout(location=1) out int o_ObjectID;
        in vec3 v_Colors;

        in flat int v_ObjectID;
        void main()
        {
            color=vec4(v_Colors,1.0);
            o_ObjectID = 50;
        };
```

I have fragment and vertex shader for Quads and Circles (I sent shaders for circles)

I want to read value :50 (because I set second output as 50 as you can see above) from FBO.ReadPixels(...) for specified pixel  but it returns 0 on the other hand the firs output of fragment shader works as ı expected and shows colors.If ı Set `o_ObjectID` as the first output
and make the `m_RendererColorAttachment[1]` attached to `GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0` and try to read it from there function returns the value 50. (By the way that specified Xpos,Ypos (450,360) are in the range of circle's coordinates.) So ı searched the Internet to find how to solve it. I found related topics but ı still couldn't figured it out.

Comment: Are you missing a call to `glDrawBuffers` to specify that you have two color attachments?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to setting up the FBO, you also need to specify which buffers are mapped to which output of the fragment shader. This is done by calling `glDrawBuffers` (or `glNamedFramebufferDrawBuffers`) and passing an array that specifies for each fragment shader output location which attachment to use.

For your case, the following code should work

```
GLuint attachments[2] = { GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT1 };
glDrawBuffers(2, attachments);
```

Comment: Oh ı don't know how ı missed that thanks for your help